# Validation is working but the form is not submiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Yeah, I know I had one question like this but this is new...

I have in code that every form field to validate if is blank or not that I need but when I press submit nothing happens. (I deactivate the standard submit)

```
let classes = (classes) => document.getElementsByClassName(classes);

let username = id("nume"),
  email = id("email"),
  form = id("contactForm"),
  telefon = id("telefon"),
  localitate = id("localitate"),
  detalii = id("detalii"),
  data = id("data"),
  specializare = id("specializare"),
  medic = id("medic"),
  agree = id("agree"),
  errorMsg = classes("error");

// Adding the submit event Listener

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  engine(nume, 0, "Introdu un nume valid");
  engine(email, 1, "Introdu o adresa de email valida");
  engine(telefon, 2, "Introdu un număr de telefon valid");
  engine(localitate, 3, "Introdu o localitate valida");
  engine(detalii, 4, "Introdu o informație detaliată cu ce vă supără");
  engine(data, 5, "Alege o dată pentru programare");
  engine(specializare, 6, "Selectează specialitatea");
  engine(medic, 7, "Alege medicul pe care îl dorești");
  engine(agree, 8, "Trebuie sa fi deacord cu termenii și condițiile noastre");
});

// engine function which will do all the works


let engine = (id, serial, message) => {
  if (id.value.trim() === "") {
    errorMsg[serial].innerHTML = message;
    id.style.border = "2px solid red";
  } else {
    errorMsg[serial].innerHTML = "";
    id.style.border = "2px solid green";
  }
};
```

I have my .PHP email sender connected with action, but how can I make if all fields are green I can press submit?

Comment: Please include your html as well. Is there an error in your console?

Comment: `preventDefault()` is always executed regardless of your "validation"...

Comment: You need to evaluate if any of the inputs fail, probably by returning a value from the `engine` function. Then if everything is good, submit the form. `e.preventDefault()` prevents the submission of the form, so you have to force the submission.

Comment: call `e.preventDefault();` when some of validation fails

Comment: @mykaf There are no errors :) I just force myself to not send the form when I press the submit button but to stay on the page because I want when a User is entering nothing in form field an error pop saying "Blank space" but I don't know exactly how to force via JAVASCRIPT to check if all spaces are OK and offer permission to Submit.